# Why are objects visible when set not to be?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I have no idea why this is happening, I revised everything I made (all the logic) to make sure nothing was "odd." I have a simple prop ("active"), all it does is the following: if it is true, the object is visible, if it is false, the object is invisible. *Works*, right? **No**, it *does not work*! I have no idea why. It always used to work, but suddenly it stopped. I have another object (weapon) with the **exact** same logic, and that one works. Can anyone tell me *why* this possibly is happening? Also, when I start the scene and *the object is visible when the property is false*, it can be fixed by toggling the prop to false, then back to true. The problem with this is that I need the object to be invisible **at the start** and not after I toggle the prop on and off till it *works*.

**EDIT: Here is what I think the problem *really* is: at the *very start* of the game engine (as soon as I hit "P", it is visible when it is not supposed to be *unless* I toggle the property a couple of times. In other words, why is it visible at the *very start* rather than when it is supposed to be?**

Comment: I have *3* weapons so far, and **2 out of 3** are having this issue. They all *basically* have the same logic.

Comment: Once more, can you show the setup with an image or a .blend file? It is hard to guess with nothing provided.

Comment: Well, I mean, I have 2 scenes with a **very, very** complex setup, but at the final product, when I use *debug properties enabled*, the prop is false, and the object is invisible.

Comment: What did you change when it stopped working?

Comment: @Anson Savage I didn't change anything, I simply didnt notice it. What's odd is that it **does work** when I  toggle it back to true then false.

Comment: @blackhole That is strange. I had a similar problem when using an action actuator, but I think it is unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that had this issue, I just made our prop "active" set to true **by default.** I do not know why this is the case, but it is.